# Maximum Value Of CSS Property Text Shadow Blur

Tags: css

I was just wondering what could be the maximum value of CSS property blur in 'text-shadow'?

As the value keep on increasing it is hard to see any changes because things start getting blurred up.

```
text-shadow:0 0 0px #000;
```

[image]

```
text-shadow:0 0 10px #000;
```

[image]

```
text-shadow:0 0 50px #000;
```

[image]

```
text-shadow:0 0 100px #000;
```

[image]

```
text-shadow:0 0 200px #000;
```

[image]

```
text-shadow:0 0 300px #000;
```

[image]

```
text-shadow:0 0 400px #000;
```

[image]

300px and 400px looks pretty much same. As we keep on increasing I don't see any difference. May be few pixels are fading away / moving away that are hard to notice. I believe that it will be different for each browser.

Kind of unproductive question but I believe that we can at least increase our knowledge about this.

Comment: i think its never create a Bug in Design :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<sub>*Disclaimer*: I hope I can express this in English correctly. Please feel free to correct this answer.</sub>

This is how *blur* is defined: [7.2. Drop Shadows: the ‘box-shadow’ property](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#box-shadow)

> The third length is a **blur radius**. Negative values are not allowed. If the blur value is zero, the shadow's edge is sharp. Otherwise, the larger the value, the more the shadow's edge is blurred.
>
> A non-zero blur distance indicates that the resulting shadow should be blurred, such as by a **Gaussian filter**. The exact algorithm is not defined; however the resulting shadow must approximate (with each pixel being within 5% of its expected value) the image that would be generated by applying to the shadow a **Gaussian blur with a standard deviation** equal to half the blur radius.

So you see that the blur radius is used in a [Gaussian Filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_filter) with a defined [*standard deviation*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation).

Take a look at this image:

[image]

<sub>from [Wikipedia "Gauß-Filter"](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss-Filter) (German, English link above)</sub>

You see that as greater the values get the smoother the edges become but it doens't distribute the other values differently.

Answer (score 2):

There's no such thing called maximum for the blur, you are just setting the radius too high, which is just making the effect useless, set it to minimal.

So the more the radius you set, the more `blur` the `text-shadow` gets, let me illustrate this you with an image, we have a font, and we have set the size say `12px` and a radius say `100px`, the blur effect will be negligible here..

[image]

In the above image, the font is in the center, and shadow is spanned across large area(Black border), thus it diminishes the effect of the `text-shadow` as you are setting the `blur` value too high.

But if you set it proportionally, it will show up as you expect it should

[image]

[**Demo 1**](http://jsfiddle.net/JMDTY/) (Negligible for second `p`)

[**Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/JMDTY/1/) (Making it propotional)